# Finding the area of a polygon feature in a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, polygon, area

Excuse the very simple question. How do i find the area of a selected polygon feature in a shapefile?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: It's not that simple if you have to do it programmatically :-)

Comment: similar question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30006/how-to-calculate-polygon-areas-and-perimeters (QGIS specific)

Answer (score 4):

Not trying to be terse, but given that you are using shapefiles it may be reasonale to assume you might have access to ArcGIS. If so, the directions here:

http://soa.utexas.edu/crp/gis/arcgis_tips/area_calculation.html

are quite clear.

then simply select the polygon and look at your attribute table.

Answer GetSpatial's question and there are plenty of other options