# Calculating polygon areas and perimeters using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, area, measurements

Using QGIS, if I load a polygon layer and make a new column, how do I fill that column with the area of each polygon and another column with the length of the perimeter of each polygon?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Open the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator), select the new column and type the following expression

- For area : [`$area`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#area)
- For perimeter: [`$perimeter`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#perimeter)

Make sure your layer is in a projected coordinate system (not lat/long) and in correct units (i.e. if your layer's projection has 'meters' as units, your area will be square meters).

Note that reprojecting layers on-the-fly does not change the units for area/perimeter calculation, so you have to first reproject using Save as ... with the correct target CRS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

For QGIS versions 2.16 and above (see the [Changelog for QGIS 2.16](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog216/index.html#feature-ftools-plugin-has-been-replaced-with-processing-algorithms)) use the ["Add geometry attributes"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#add-geometry-attributes) tool from `Vector > Geometry Tools > Add geometry attributes`.

You also can use fTools: *Vector menu -> Geometry Tools -> Export/Add geometry columns*

It updates your layer automatically by adding `"AREA"` and `"PERIMETER"` columns.