# How to calculate area of a polygon in a shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to calculate areas of different polygons in QGIS in tabular format.

Comment: Welcome :-) This question is a subset of an already answered question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30006/how-to-calculate-polygon-areas-and-perimeters-using-qgis The first rule of posting a question is doing a proper search.  I believe your question will be marked as a duplicate and eventually removed. Do not take it personally :-) Building a good QA base requires this process.

Answer (score 1):

For a single polygon you can use the Identify Features toolbutton. In the Identify Result dialog look under Derived for the area of the clicked polygon.

http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html

If you want to update or make a new column with the area use the Field Calculator and the function Geometry > area$. The dollar sign just tells you that the function takes no arguments from you.

http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html?highlight=field%20calculator

The Identify Feature and Field Calculator buttons:

[image]

You can also access the Field Calculator within the Attribute window.