# How to calculate area in sq m - troubleshooting projection issues in a global dataset in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, coordinate-system, area

I am using QGIS version 2.12.3.

I have 3 polygon shapefiles: A, B and the intersect of A and B, which we can call C.

All I want is to add a field to the attributes table of each shapefile giving the area (in square m or square km) of each feature in that layer.  A, B and C each contain upwards of 10,000 individual features (polygons of protected areas), distributed over every continent.

I have used a global projection (WGS 84/NSIDC EASE Grid-Global EPSG:3975, have also tried 3410), which is listed under 'Projected Coordinate Systems' so I assume it is projected and not geographical, and set this as the coordinate system for the project and each one of the layers.

When I use the field calculation tool and the $area function, the resulting field values are definitely not in square m or square km and bear no resemblance to area as I understand it.

I have run it several times having fiddled with settings that I'm fairly sure I don't understand, and I've ended up with either really tiny values (e.g. 0.0000002345) or random sets of values including negative numbers.

Can anyone identify where I've gone wrong and suggest how I can go about completing this fairly simple task?

Comment: Can you post the EPSG code of that particular WGS 84 projection?  Because what first comes to mind is: you are using degrees and not meters as units.

Comment: Have you checked http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30006/how-to-calculate-polygon-areas-and-perimeters-using-qgis?rq=1

Comment: The EPSG is 3975, have also tried 3410.  Both say 'units=m' in the description.  Have set measurement units in project properties to meters as well.  If these CRS are in degrees, what global projection can I use that will allow area calc in meters?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[WGS 84/NSIDC EASE Grid-Global](http://georepository.com/crs_3974/WGS-84-NSIDC-EASE-Grid-South.html) seems to be a [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Cartography), which does not preserve areas. This is the reason why you can't get meaningful results.

The most simple solution is to reproject your layer to a UTM projection suited to your area of interest.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this, but my area of interest is the whole world.  The analysis does not allow breaking down any further.  Any advice on a global projection that will allow area calculation?

Comment: Ok, maybe have a look at [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20054/coordinate-system-for-calculating-areas-of-polygons-accurately). It is advised to use a cylindrical equal-area projection.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your advice, but I have had a look and the projections I was using ARE equal area cylindrical projections and are listed as such.  In theory, then, I should be able to calculate area in sq meters?  Where else could I be going wrong?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

All used shp-Files have the EPSG 31468.

I run the model, add a field and calculate the area the sum of all records will be 10275 m²[image]

When I do the same with field calculator form the gui the sum of all records will be 10311 m². When I use a other gis I get always this result
[image]