# Calculate polygon area in QGIS 2.18

Tags: polygon, geometry, qgis-2, shape-area

I'm trying to calculate a polygon area. This is the polygon and the attribute table:

[image]

When I open field calculator and use the Geometry--> area$, the area result for ID 1 is (in square meters) 1809477.67:

[image]

but when i use the `Export/Add geometry column` tool, two things happen:

1. a new layer been created named "added geom info"- why the data isn't created in the polygon attribute table?
2. the area result is (in square meters): 1799292.92 - why I get different results?

[image]

[image]

When I measure the area in ArcGIS 10.3 - the result was 1799292.92 square meters.

I also read

[How to calculate polygon areas and perimeters using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30006/how-to-calculate-polygon-areas-and-perimeters-using-qgis)

but didn't find any suitable answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Export/Add geometry column tool states:

> This algorithm computes geometric properties of the features in a vector layer. **It generates a new vector layer** with the same content as the input one, but with additional attributes in its attributes table, containing geometric measurements.
>   Depending on the geometry type of the vector layer, the attributes added to the table will be different.

You can calculate the area directly from the attribute table. Crate a new decimal/real field, and use the `$area` expression.

The values will correspond to the layer CRS

[image]

Comment: HDunn, why i get two different results?