# Calculate perimeter of a large polygon using geodesic calculations

Tags: vector, length, geodesic

How do I calculate perimeter of a large vector polygon (polygon set) which spans almost half the globe? I guess [regular calculations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30006/how-to-calculate-polygon-areas-and-perimeters-using-qgis) do not produce accurate results in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS, it seems that if you have the project coordinate reference system set to an ellipsoid and not a projection, then calculating the perimeter via the field calculator will automatically use the ellipsoidal value:

[image]

In ArcGIS, the tool [**Add Geometry Attributes**](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm) appears to give you an entire suite of geometrical and geographical calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using web mercator projection  and addGeometryAtributes form ArcGIS